# field number theory question

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory

If we have ${a+b\sqrt{-1}}$ for a,b in ${Z_p}$, with $p$ as an odd prime, with $\sqrt{-1}^2=-1$, how do we show that $a+b\sqrt{-1}$ has a multiplicative inverse iff $a-b\sqrt{-1}$ has a multiplicative inverse, iff $a^2+b^2$ has a multiplicative inverse.

I know that $(a+b\sqrt{-1})(a-b\sqrt{-1})=a^2+b^2$ but I"m not sure how that works here.

Comment: multiplicative inverse " where "???

Comment: in the field, I think?

Comment: which field?? $\mathbb{Z}_p$?? I guess No!

Comment: I assume in $\Bbb Z_p(\sqrt{-1})$.

Comment: Ah sorry, yeah, Arthur is right.

Comment: But you've said yourself that this is a field, thus all non-zero elements have a multiplicative inverse. Or are you trying to show that $\Bbb Z_p(\sqrt{-1})$ _is_ a field?

Comment: I am trying to show it is a field so I am trying to prove the above. That each of those have a multiplicative inverse if and only if the others do.

Comment: Consider $\sigma(a+b\sqrt{-1}) = a - b\sqrt{-1}$. How does that interplay with multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

If $a^2 + b^2$ has an inverse, then the inverse of $a + b \sqrt{-1}$ is $(a^2 + b^2)^{-1} (a - b \sqrt{-1})$. And similarly you can prove the other equivalences.

Comment: Unless $a^2 + b^2 = 0$....

Answer (score 1):

Prove that $$(a+b\sqrt{-1})(c+d\sqrt{-1})=1$$ if and only if $$(a-b\sqrt{-1})(c-d\sqrt{-1})=1$$ if and only if $$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=1$$